# Error on line 117 exception unhandled

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

What am i doing wrong? I am trying to have my program read the data from a csv file but i keep getting this unhandled exception, is it because of how i wrote the txt file? the exception?

First I tried to have the data be displayed as a list in the console, but that did not happened either. I cant seem to be able to do that here or even get it right to read from my txt file.

```
//My first program 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PracticeProgram
{
public class Program
{
    public static bool W2 { get; private set; }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        List<Person> myContacts = new List<Person>();

        // Loop to collect developers data
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)

         {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome developer, enter your name to continue");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + name);

            Console.WriteLine("enter your address");
            string address = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(address);

            Console.WriteLine("enter your monthly income");
            double GrossMonthlyPay = 5000;
            Console.WriteLine(GrossMonthlyPay);
            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("your tax deduction is set at 7%");
            double taxes = (0.07);
            Console.WriteLine(taxes);
            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("your monthly tax deduction is ");
            Console.WriteLine(taxes = GrossMonthlyPay * taxes);
            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Based on your monthly income your Annual gross pay is ");
            double AnnualGrossPay = GrossMonthlyPay * 12;
            Console.WriteLine(AnnualGrossPay);
            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Your annual taxes are ");
            double AnnualTaxes = AnnualGrossPay * 0.07;
            Console.WriteLine(AnnualTaxes);
            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Select 1 for W2, select 2 for 1099");
            bool A = W2;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();

            if (A)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You employment type is W2");
            }
             else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your employment type is 1099");
            }                           

            Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();

            myContacts.Add(new Person(name, address, GrossMonthlyPay, taxes, AnnualGrossPay, AnnualTaxes));
        }
        // Or you could read from CSV or any other source
        foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\new\data.txt"))
        {
            myContacts.Add(Person.ReadFromCSV(line));
        }

        // Serialize your informations at the end
        foreach (Person contact in myContacts)
        {
            contact.SerializeToCSV(@"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\new\data.txt");
        }
    }
}

internal class Person
{
    private string address;
    private double grossMonthlyPay;
    private string name;
    private double taxes;
    private double annualGrossPay;
    private double annualTaxes;

    public Person(string name, string address, double grossMonthlyPay, double taxes)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.grossMonthlyPay = grossMonthlyPay;
        this.taxes = taxes;
    }

    public Person(string name, string address, double grossMonthlyPay, double taxes, double annualGrossPay, double annualTaxes) : this(name, address, grossMonthlyPay, taxes)
    {
        this.annualGrossPay = annualGrossPay;
        this.annualTaxes = annualTaxes;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Name=" + this.name + ",Address =" + this.address + " Monthly Pay=" + this.grossMonthlyPay + " Taxes=" + this.taxes.ToString();
    }

    internal static Person ReadFromCSV(string line)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    internal void SerializeToCSV(string v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYMP5.png)

Comment: which line shows the error? and what is the error message says

Comment: line 117 @un-lucky, it tells me that the method or operation is not implemented, not sure what this means since I already did

Comment: @un-lucky, i have added a screenshot for reference. no need to get mad, i'm just trying to learn.

Comment: **Your own code** is throwing the exception.  use the debugger, set a breakpoint on the last foreach and step thru it.  BTW, writing to a CSV is not the same as serializing.  Also, next time spend more time on your title to describe the actual problem and less time telling us your opinion of java vs c#

Comment: @Plutonix I'm not trying to write to a CSV i'm trying to read from it, which is what I thought I wrote on my code. Dang this is harder than I thought.

Comment: Well, your code calls `SerializeToCSV` (which throws the exception).  There is also a `ReadFromCSV` so I *assume* that the first writes to the CSV but thats not serialization.

Answer (score 1):

Your function "ReadFromCSV" implement a

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

try to delete it or implement with the right code